# create a conditional base on switch value

Tags: material-ui, android-jetpack-compose

If the switch is checked I want one  R.drawable if not I want another, could you help me, please?

I'm using a data base, viewmodel, room. I just don't know how to properly write the conditional

```
@Composable
fun PetCard(userInfo: PetEntity, mPetViewModel: PetViewModel) {
    Card(
        shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.large,
        elevation = 5.dp,
        backgroundColor= MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(195.dp)
            .padding(5.dp)
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Image(painter = if (userInfo.vPetsSpecies != null) {
            painterResource(id = R.drawable.pet_cat)
        } else {
            painterResource(id = R.drawable.pet_dog)
        },
            contentDescription = "Pet",
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
        )
        Text(text = userInfo.vPetName,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(10.dp),
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineMedium,
            textAlign= TextAlign.Left
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: Thanks Gabriele, I already managed to find the solution 